# Ms dynamics merge two records using Java

Tags: java, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have downloaded the Ms Dynamics integration packages for Java (not the SDK). I am able to create, update and delete all entities. But now, I am trying to merge two contacts in Ms Dynamics Crm using Java. Research has led me nowhere. Classes like MergeRequest are there for JavaScript, but I am not sure how to go about with Java. I have created the two contacts, and have retrieved them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you use SOAP for CRUD operations. Here is Soap for Merging of records:

```
POST https://pactest.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <request i:type="b:MergeRequest" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts">
        <a:Parameters xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <c:key>Target</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="a:EntityReference">
              <a:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:Id>
              <a:LogicalName>account</a:LogicalName>
              <a:Name i:nil="true" />
            </c:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <c:key>SubordinateId</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="d:guid" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</c:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <c:key>UpdateContent</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="a:Entity">
              <a:Attributes />
              <a:EntityState i:nil="true" />
              <a:FormattedValues />
              <a:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:Id>
              <a:LogicalName>account</a:LogicalName>
              <a:RelatedEntities />
            </c:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <c:key>PerformParentingChecks</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="d:boolean" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">true</c:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
        </a:Parameters>
        <a:RequestId i:nil="true" />
        <a:RequestName>Merge</a:RequestName>
      </request>
    </Execute>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Of course you should replace Guid.Empty with correct ids of records you want to merge.

Comment: I made all the entities into Classes, in order to make the process more Object-oriented. I will try to mock the same request with my objects and update. Thanks for the response.

Comment: When i do merge two accounts in this case, which parameter do i change to edit the the winning fields? For eg, can I make one field of the losing account to be retained?